# Fetching a specific value from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this kind of an array.

```
Array( [data](
 [0] =>array(
          are_fb_friends =>false.
           name =>pickman
           id => 1000 )
 [1] => array( 
         are_fb_friends => false
          name => dennis
           id => 2000 )
 [2] => array(
         are_fb_friends => false
          name => Emmanuel 
          id => 3000 ) ) )
```

I would like to get the specific name for the index 2.
Like i need a something that would return `Emmanuel`. Just like it would if i had this kind of query in sql `Select name FROM data WHERE index = 2`

Am looking for a function in php that would do something similar with an array. 
I have tried this.

```
$ column= array_column($data, 'id');
 $index=array_search(3000,$column);
 echo "$data[$index][name]";
```

I get this error.
     `Array to string conversation.`

Comment: Try `$arr[2]['name']`

Comment: @Ivan i still get the same error

Comment: May be `$arr['data'][2]['name']`   - I do not clearly understand `Array( [data](` - what is '[data]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as that:

```
$name = $data[2]['name'];
// or $array['data'][2]['name'] - depends how your array looks like
echo $name; // will print "Emmanuel"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
function getName($index, $array) {
    return (isset($array[$index]['name']) ? $array[$index]['name'] : null)
}
```

usage

```
$name = getName(2, $nameArray);
```

If the value exists returns the name, if not the result will be null.